# Where do I add my intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is what I am trying to set up: My Android app requires email confirmation. They register using my app, and then an email is sent to them with a link. I want to have that link open the app directly, but I've been told it's better to have the link open page on my web site that in turn opens the app using a redirect. The link also sends the user's email address and a verification code.

Okay, so, do that, my understanding is that I need to add this code to my `AndroidManifest.xml` (where MYAPP is the name of my web site):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="MYAPP.com" android:path="/confirmation.html" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And then my web site has a page with this in the `<head>` (where MYAPP is the name of my app):

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=MYAPP://?verification=' . $_GET["verification"] . '&email=' . $_GET["email"] . '"/>
```

It's not working, and I'm possibly making multiple mistakes.

First question is, where does my `<intent-filter>` go? I've only read that it goes within the `<activity>` tags, but in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have two `<activity>` tags:

```
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MYAPP" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap">
        <intent-filter />
    </activity>
```

I tried adding my `<intent-filter>` in one, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MYAPP" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="MYAPP.com" android:path="/confirmation.html" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap">
        <intent-filter />
    </activity>
```

Where do I put my `<intent-filter>`?

Is the rest of my code, especially my redirect URL, okay?

Please note I am a beginner and I am using Phonegap to build this app, so please do not assume I know a great deal about Android app development. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had my intent filter in the right place.

The reason it wasn't working was simply because I needed an extra line to account for `https` links.

So my code now looks like this:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="MYAPP.com" android:path="/confirmation.html" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="MYAPP.com" android:path="/confirmation.html" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside you activity tags like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".My_Activity_Name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application
```

In this code of yours, where is the starting intent-filter tag for the last activity:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MYAPP" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="MYAPP.com" android:path="/confirmation.html" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap">
    <intent-filter />
</activity>
```